# Sorting alphabetically type of hashmap <string,string> ANDROID

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, hashmap, android-adapter

After implementing the Hashmap I realized that it was not sorted alphabetically so now I wanted to know if there's another map that sorts the files for me?
I tried using the code above but it says that I can't use sort in my listview type

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList =
     new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Collections.sort(songsList, new Comparator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: you can't use a `Comparator<String>` on `HashMap`, because `HashMap` is not `String`. (you need a `Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>`)

Comment: public `List`<`Map`<String, String>> songsList = new `ArrayList`<`HashMap`<String, String>>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** -

You can just use the following -

```
    Collections.sort(songsList,new Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>(){
public int compare(HashMap<String,String> mapping1,
                    HashMap<String,String> mapping2){
    return mapping1.get("KEY").compareToIgnoreCase(mapping2.get("KEY"));
}
```

**NOTE:** Replace KEY with your key.

Answer (score 0):

to store your data sorted you could also use the [Sorted Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/SortedMap.html). then you should have no more problems with sorting the Map.

Greetings.

--- EDIT ---
SortedMap is an Interface, which is implemented by TreeMap. So if you want to use a custom Comparator you can easily implement SortedMap. As an minimal sample (with a treemap):

```
private static List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        map.put("A", "a");
        map.put("D", "d");
        map.put("B", "b");
        map.put("C", "c");
        list.add(map);
    }

    for (Map<String, String> map : list){
        for (String element : map.values()) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

}
```

To implement a SortedMap by yourself take a look at: [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ASortedMapimplementationfordealingwithfuzzykeysAbinarysearchisusedtofindtheclosestkeytotheinput.htm)